# How to scaffold all finder methods in Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

How I can see all list of ActiveRecord methods ..which I can add by make:

finder list
finder add...

And then something like this:

web mvc scaffold --class name --entity MyActiveRecordEntity_which_include_all_posible_methods

and of course I must see all of this methods in web interface. Great thnks!

Comment: and how I can add simply methods to the web interface by Roo? Is it posible?

Comment: methods not only of active_records but and some other classes.

Comment: so easy)))      finder list && finder add XXXXXX && web mvc finder add --formBackingType ~.domain.XX --class ~.web.XXX_finder

Comment: OK. PLEASE CLOSE THIS THREAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so easy))) finder list && finder add XXXXXX && web mvc finder add --formBackingType ~.domain.XX --class ~.web.XXX_finder